# .Net WCF service with Soap 1.2, no addressing. How to force the SoapAction to be read from a different header node

Tags: .net, wcf-binding, soapserver

We are working with .NET with a 3rd party which has requested that we expose a WCF Endpoint with SOAP 1.2 without addressing.
They, however, indicated that it is a custom implementation which they send the Soap Action in a specific soap header XML element and not in the content-type as the specification indicates.
I have been trying to manipulate the request on receiving by using Custom Bindings, Endpoint behaviours, IDispatchOperationSelector but nothing is working. I always get the error "The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher." before entering AfterReceiveRequest (IDispatchMessageInspector) or SelectOperation (IDispatchOperationSelector).
I would not want to construct the full hosting process and would like to know if there is a way to get the Soap action from a different node and inject it as the addressing soap header or in content-type before it tries to validate that the action exists in the contracts...
If this is not enough information please let me know.
Thank you in advance.

---

**Update**

After some searching and reading I found a workaround:

1. Added a generic Unactioned contract in the WCF contracts class
   `[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "*", ReplyAction = "*")]`    and added names to all operations in the
   service.
2. Added an additional IEndpointBehavior class with
   ApplyDispatchBehavior which registers the OperationSelector to a new
   IDispatchOperationSelector.
3. Added an IDispatchOperationSelector
   which gets the action from the custom header and returns it as the
   operation name.
4. In the WCF service class implementation added the
   UnActioned operation with throwing exception as a fallback in case a
   wrong operation is sent.

Ran into some issues like the Operation name cannot contain ":" but that was simple to discuss with the 3rd party to change.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The client-side and server-side must have the same binding and contract, otherwise this problem will occur.

Comment: HI Ding Peng. For the server (my side) to be conformant with the client side, I need to have the .net WCF service (my side) read the soap action from a custom node in the soap header:




<soap:Header>
    <CustomHeader>
      <timeStamp>2021-05-04T12:56:32+00:00</timeStamp>
      <echoToken>2wZ79k301bhGmj4VkXTEgEZm</echoToken>
     **<action>SomeAction</action>**
    </CustomHeader>
  </soap:Header>





Or be able to pick this up and inject it as part of the content-type header before the .net system tries to correlate with the operation in the contract.